# Netsuite query is not returning Currency Revaluation value

Tags: web-services, netsuite, suitetalk

**API:**

https://tstdrv243232323232.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql?limit=1000

**query:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM Transaction 
INNER JOIN TransactionAccountingLine 
  ON ( TransactionAccountingLine.Transaction = Transaction.ID ) 
INNER JOIN Account 
  ON ( Account.ID = TransactionAccountingLine.Account ) 
where Account.accttype IN('AcctPay') 
  AND BUILTIN.DF( Transaction.Entity ) IS NOT NULL 
  AND (Transaction.DueDate<='12/29/2021') 
  AND ( Transaction.Posting = 'T' ) 
  AND ( Transaction.Voided = 'F' ) 
  AND (( TransactionAccountingLine.AmountUnpaid <> 0 ) 
    OR ( TransactionAccountingLine.PaymentAmountUnused <> 0 )) 
ORDER BY Transaction.TranDate ASC
```

[Related screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8iaA.png)

Comment: Most likely something in your WHERE is filtering those lines out of the result. Try removing one condition at a time and re-run the query to check. My guess would be AcctType for the currency revaluation lines is not AccPay and you need to add another value to the IN(). Keep checking to see which condition(s) is/are the issue.

Comment: I agree with @brian, but I think the culprit could be the `TransactionAccountingLine.AmountUnpaid` and `TransactionAccountingLine.PaymentAmountUnused`, since I don't believe these fields exist on a Currency Revaluation Transaction.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.